# Entity Framework 6 - How to count items in a many-to-many relationship via a single query?

Tags: count, frameworks, many-to-many, entity

Apologies for the noob EF question but I'm struggling to get this working and have definitely reached the **Ask For Help** stage :)

Here are two simplified classes:

```
public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public IList<CourseTag> CourseTags { get; set; }
...
}

 public class CourseTag
        { 

            public int Id { get; set; } 
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
...
}
```

I simply want to Count the number of CourseTags that are related to a course, **in a single query.**

I can **SELECT** the courses for a particular CourseTagId (as below), which SELECTS the courses just fine...

```
from course in Courses
 from tag in course.CourseTags
 where tag.Id == 3
 select course
```

BUT I can't work out how to **Count** the number of **Courses** that are related to a particular **CourseTag** (without using an additional, separate query)

I've tried variations along the lines of the following, but just can't figure the correct syntax...

```
from course in Courses
            from tag in course.CourseTags
            where tag.Id == 3
            **course.Count()??**
```

I've worked out how to separate this into two queries to get the result - but it seems unnecessary to perform two queries just to count something - **there must be a way to simplify this into a single query?**

```
var courseResult = from course in Courses
            from tag in course.CourseTags
            where tag.Id == 3
            select course;

var totalNumber = courseResult.Count();
```

I'm sure this must be simple (it would be easy if NOT using EF/Linq) but I have a total brain block with EF/Linq. Any pointers would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems that this is one way to reduce it down to a single query. Not sure if I've actually gained anything now though but since no-one else has any suggestions hopefully this might help someone else.

```
var result = Courses.SelectMany(c => c.CourseTags.Select(t => new { c, t })) //anon obj of course with tag
.Where(c => (c.t.Id == 3)) //filter by TagId == 3
.Select(c => c.c.Id) //limit result to a single field - no need to pull all the data just to count it
.Count();
```

This selects the Course AND it's related (many to many) Tags as an anonymous object - (**c, t**) is the Course and Tag.

**SelectMany** flattens the resulting data, so that it can be counted.